# Looping across files to overlay contours from different datasets onto one pcolor map

Tags: matplotlib, contour, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to have a `pcolor` plot from one dataset on a polar stereographic grid, and then overlay many contours for one level , but these contours are being defined from a 3d dataset of their own.  I am getting the error:

> RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure

```py
# load lat lons 

fid = Dataset(ifile_for_lat_lon)
lon=fid.variables['TLON'][:]
lat=fid.variables['TLAT'][:]
fid.close()

def get_basemap():
        fig = plt.figure('Background')
        fig.add_subplot(111)
        m = Basemap(projection='npstere',boundinglat=65,lon_0=270,resolution='l')
        x,y = m(lon,lat) # compute map proj coordinates
        m.pcolor(x,y,raster_data,vmin=0,vmax=1,cmap='Blues_r')
        m.colorbar(location='right')
        m.drawcoastlines()
        m.fillcontinents(color='grey',lake_color='navy')
        # draw parallels and meridians.
        m.drawparallels(np.arange(-80.,81.,20.))
        m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181.,20.))
        m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='navy')
        plt.legend(loc='lower right')
        return m,x,y

# run get_basemap once to get background map
m,x,y = get_basemap()

for year in np.arange(1979,2017):
        year=str(year)
        # contour levels
        clevs=np.array([0.7])

        # load data
        nc_fid = Dataset(ifile,'r')
        data = nc_fid.variables['data'][0,:,:]
        nc_fid.close()

        cnplot = m.contour(x,y,data,clevs,cmap=plt.cm.jet,linewidth=20) 

        #for member in cnplot.collections: 
        #       member.remove()
        plt.show()
```

The first plot of the loop works fine -- the background raster with associated contour is displayed.

As soon as the loop goes through the second iteration, it complains there

> RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure

I just want the loop so I can read the new rasters so it knows where to put the overlaying contours.  So, in the end, I need a background raster with a lot of contours on top (but those rasters will not be displayed, just the contour level information from them on top of the original background from the first file)

Comment: I don't think  `plt.show()` makes sense *inside*  the loop. You first need to plot everything, then you can call `plt.show()`. Of course everything would be easier with a [mcve].

Comment: Hi, I have spent a lot of time trying to make a minimal reproducible example, but I cannot figure out how to get the data into the question.  I do not have the osgeo module, which I have seen can give some 3d datasets.  If you have a suggeestion of how to incorporate the data please point me in a direction.

Comment: Use other data, that is easy to construct via code.

Comment: Hi, this plt.show() was the problem.  I am not sure if I can accept a comment on this website, but this solved it thanks

Comment: No you cannot accept comments. Since I have no interest in providing an answer which simply says "Put `plt.show()` out of the loop, you can do so yourself. Or delete the question.

Comment: I am not sure why plt.show() has to be put outside of the loop, as to me, I wanted to see it being plotted interactively.  It was a big help and not obvious to me why this works.